Cannot use fetch_california_housing. How to solve this?
I tried executing this code. But I am getting an error. How do I solve this?
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing

x = fetch_california_housing()

Error
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

